# Setting up LWJGL 3.0 with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, lwjgl

Downloaded `LWJGL 3.0` from `lwjgl.org`, which only had the *lwjgl.jar* file in the jar subdirectory. The native directory only has files like *libglfw.so* but no subdirectories at all (and certainly not native/windows).

Created a library `LWJGL30` with the *lwjgl.jar* file.
Added it to my project's library. and to the `Project Properties->Libraries->Compile and Run`.
Set the JVM launch argument in `Project Properties->Run to -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Owner\Documents\lwjgl\native for the VM Options`

Copied the HelloWorld example from the [link](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide)

Then ran and I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>
> initialize class org.lwjgl.system.Library     at
>
> org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.(MemoryAccess.java:22)  at
>
> org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.(Pointer.java:22)    at
>
> org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.(GLFW.java:594)   at
>
> mylwjgl.MyLWJGL.run(MyLWJGL.java:43)  at
>
> mylwjgl.MyLWJGL.main(MyLWJGL.java:140)
>
> C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>
> Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)

I have checked, double checked, triple checked as well as searching online for an answer as it should work but it does not. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when LWJGL is unable to find the native files. Make sure `java.library.path` actually points to the directory with LWJGL's natives (which have extensions like `.dll`, `.so` and `.dylib`). Be careful with spaces in the path: You have to wrap the path in quotation marks or it won't work.

Comment: No spaces in path. But tried with ""

-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Owner\Documents\lwjgl\native"

-Djava.library.path="C:/Users/Owner/Documents/lwjgl/native"

Tried various combines to no effect. 

This is the path and I can find the natives - C:\Users\Owner\Documents\lwjgl\native

Comment: Added     File folder = new File("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/lwjgl/native");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }

Which shows 

File jemalloc.dll
File jemalloc32.dll
File libglfw.dylib
File libglfw.so
File libglfw32.so
File libjemalloc.dylib
File libjemalloc.so
File libjemalloc32.so
File liblwjgl.dylib
File liblwjgl.so
File liblwjgl32.so
File libopenal.dylib
File libopenal.so
File libopenal32.so
File Thumbs.db

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was running the HelloWorld example using the Stable version of LWJGL 3.0. When I switched to the Latest version, everything worked as expected.